# Wordpress admin-ajax.php works on localhost but not server

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I'm using ajax to filter custom post types in WordPress. On my localhost (xampp) everything works fine and runs well, filters and displays the appropriate posts.

Thus far I've rebuilt the whole site to verify my core files are in tact. I checked the database to make sure my wp-options home and sit urls were set correctly. I've tried it both in http and https as well as resaved the permalinks.

I have also contacted my hosting provider (inMotion) to verify there is nothing I need to do to enable ajax on WordPress. I also have another site running on the same server, that utilizes ajax without issue.

Essentially, what could be causes the "$home_url/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?grade-filter=&department-filter=+&search=&action=coursefilter"

to throw a GET 400 error?

Answer (score 0):

There could be couple of reasons, but most commonly it is due to pretty permalinks not being set.

Go to `Settings > Permalinks` & enable pretty permalink structure & hit **Save**. After that ensure that there is `.htaccess` file with following code:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

If you are running nginx web server, enable `Wordpress2` mode for domain then add this to your `.conf` file:

```
location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; 
}
```

Read more in official WordPress documentation: https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

**[Updated]**

> By your given information I can assume that the only things that have
>   changed since migration are the `home_url`/**domain** and serverside software such as **web server** & **PHP**

I suggest you to double check these differences, replace old URLs with new domain URLs and make sure there is no plugins or other script re-routing request of this URL.

Comment: By "pretty permalinks" do you mean by post name, if so, it is set there and it also works perfectly fine with the same permalinks structure on my localhost. My .htaccess also has that code.

Comment: Then, if there is no rewrite for this url path, It's probably the home url issue after migration. Force set them in `wp-config.php` and do `search & replace` in database. By your given information I can assume that the only things that have changed are the `home url`/`domain` and web server therefor issues are with URL routing.